# startActivityForResult is not showing as deprected in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Some time ago I worked on a new application and I noticed that `startActivityForResult` was deprecated so I had to use `ActivityResultLauncher <Intent>`

Now I am updating another application that works with `startActivityForResult` but Android Studio does not mark the method as deprecated, doing a little research I noticed that `minSdkVersion` must have the most recent API for Android Studio to show you deprecated methods, so now I have `compileSdkVersion 31` and `minSdkVersion 31` and I can already see many deprecated methods that I did not before, but startActivityForResult is still not marked, even I used the method "Analize> Inspect code" and followed the line "Java> Code maturity" but it does not show me as deprecated the times I used `startActivityForResult`

So I need your help to know why it is not marked as deprecated and this also makes me think the following, is there a possibility that there are more deprecated methods that I do not know and Android Studio does not show them to me?

I make the clarification that yesterday I updated Android Studio to the latest version (Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3) thinking that this could be the problem but I was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`startActivityForResult()` on `Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) is not deprecated.

However, [`startActivityForResult()` on `ComponentActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,int)) *is* deprecated. `ComponentActivity`, roughly speaking, is the root of all activities in the Jetpack libraries. `AppCompatActivity` extends `ComponentActivity`.

So, my guess is that:

- In the case where you are getting the deprecation warning, you are inheriting from `ComponentActivity`
- In the case where you are not getting the deprecation warning, you are not inheriting from `ComponentActivity`